# Finding $\sqrt{(1 + \sqrt{3i})}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find $\sqrt{(1 + \sqrt{3i})}$. I am trying to use the fact that $\sqrt{(1 + \sqrt{3i})} = re^{i \theta} = r(cos \theta + i sin\theta)$ but I am having trouble figuring out where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Compute out $\sqrt{3 i}$ first.

Comment: Ok. So for$\sqrt{3i} = \sqrt{3} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}) $. Would it be valid just to add $1$ and take the square root of the whole thing? @robit

Comment: Another hint: $\sqrt{re^{i\theta}}=\sqrt{r} e^{i\theta /2}$.

Comment: There are 2 square roots of 3i. And for each of them there are two square roots of your expression. It is inadvisable to use the square-root sign in complex numbers,

Answer (score 0):

JUST A HINT.- $$z=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{3i}}\iff (z^2-1)^4=-9$$ Can you get from this the eight possible values of $z$?

Comment: Did *you* use this to get a value for $z$? I just see the naive approach taking us back where the OP started, and no other approaches come to mind.

Comment: I think so. I would use de movier's theorem but I don't know how to proceed. Usually, it deals with just $z$. I don't know what to equate $(z^2 -1)^4$ to $re^{i \theta}$.

Comment: There are only 4 values for $z$ because $(z^2-1)^2=3 i.$ The other 4 of the apparent 8 are the solutions to $(z^2-1)^2=-3 i$.